# Datetime C# - Timestamp Postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql

Tengo un problema para insertar la fecha en PostgreSQL, tengo lo siguiente:

```
parametros.Add("descripcion", this.descripcion);
parametros.Add("fecha", this.fecha);
parametros.Add("estado", this.estado);

Program.da.SqlQuery("insert into schtiempos.sorteo (descripcion, fecha, estado) values (@descripcion, @fecha, @estado) returning id;", parametros);
```

Fecha en visual se encuentra como `datetime(2017/25/03 00:00:00)` y en PostgreSQL como Timestamp without time zone, pero no me deja guardarlo en la base de datos por los tipos `DateTime` y `Timestamp` without time zone, que debo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas forzar el formato de tu fecha a lo que Postgre necesita, actualmente tu propiedad **this.fecha** se imprime asi "**3/27/2017 3:02:09 PM**" y recibes el error, necesitas forzar el formato de la siguiente forma:

```
parametros.Add("descripcion", this.descripcion);

// Aqui forzamos el formato de la fecha
parametros.Add("fecha", this.fecha.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"));
parametros.Add("estado", this.estado);

Program.da.SqlQuery("insert into schtiempos.sorteo (descripcion, fecha, estado) values (@descripcion, @fecha, @estado) returning id;", parametros);
```

Asi se imprimira con el formato deseado **2017/25/03 00:00:00**

**Nota:** Esto solo funciona si this.fecha es de tipo DateTime.